# Access to all request from chrome extension level

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It is possible to have access to all request on a page from chrome extension level.
To see a list like in network tab or to be able to manipulate/filter request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the **[`chrome.webRequest` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html)** which allows you to register listeners for various events in a request's lifecycle:

- onBeforeRequest
- onBeforeSendHeaders
- onSendHeaders
- onHeadersReceived
- onAuthRequired
- onResponseStarted
- onBeforeRedirect
- onCompleted
- onErrorOccurred

Some of the events are also subject to interception and even modification (e.g. modifying the request or response headers).